# Difference between datatypes supported by Glue, Athena and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a datalake constructed on top of AWS S3. I'm using Glue catalog for storing the metadata of datalake tables. These tables will be queried using Athena and spark for various purpose.

While defining the table columns, I noticed that the data types supported by Glue, Spark and Athena are not same. Below links shows the datatypes supported by Glue, Athena and Spark

glue : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-common.html

athena : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html

spark : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html

Keeping performance in mind, which datatypes should I use while creating datalake tables,

Comment: I dont think you well notice

Comment: thebluephantom is right, you wouldn't notice them. Nonetheless, when datatype mismatch occurs on Athena table (ex: your Athena table has column datatype as INT but received "STRING" data through spark, error would show something like "typeError: int64 not understood". Thats when, you'd refer to URIs you mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah you both are right. I did not notice the datatype differences until I found a mismatch between spark and athena. My question is more from the performance stand point. I will be using spark more frequently than Athena . Do I need to create columns with Spark data types in the glue meta data catalog or I need to stick with Glue supported types.

Comment: Performance of tasks like aggregation, sort etc would depend on datatype. Hence, choose right datatype for such operations. Performance wise, both Athena/Spark infer data types in similar way if not same and shouldn't make any difference.